# $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is a group iff $p$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

I'm trying to prove  $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is a group if and only if $p$ is prime. I know that if $p$ is prime $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is a group, but how can I do the converse? In another words, if the equation $ax\equiv 1 (\mod m)$ has solution for every integer $a$ which is not divisible by $m$, then $m$ is prime.

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your question appears to be ambiguous:  $\Bbb Z_p^*$ is a group no matter what $m$ is, but $ax\equiv 1\mod m$ has a solution for all $a$ iff $m$ is prime **is** true. Do you perhaps mean $\Bbb Z_p^*$ to be $\{1,2,3,\ldots , p-1\}$? Usually it is taken to be $\{x : 0<x<p\text{ and }\gcd(x,p)=1\}$.

Comment: @AdamHughes please see my edit.

Comment: This is still false, even if $m\not | a$ you could have $\gcd(a,m)\ne 1$ take $m=6, a=9$.

Comment: @AdamHughes I'm trying to solve this exercise (see edit)

Comment: Right. Either there's a typo or your book is using a not-common notation. (See my first comment)

Comment: @AdamHughes he is probably using the asterisk to denote non-zero elements, not units.

Comment: @DavidWheeler yes, this thought had occurred to me as well (see my original comment) this is why I'm asking for clarification (books also have typos, and I don't want to guess just to find out it was a typo and have guessed wrong later)

Answer (score 2):

If $\ \color{#c00}{m = ab},\ a,b > 1\,$ then $\ {\rm mod}\,\ \color{#c00}m\!:\ \color{#0a0}{bc\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{0}\equiv (\color{#c00}{ab})c\equiv a(\color{#0a0}{bc})\equiv a,\,$ contra $\,m\nmid a$

Generally, just like $\,b\,$ above, a zero-divisor is not invertible (except in the trivial ring), which is a sort of a ring-theoretic generalization of $\,0\,$ is not invertible in a field or domain.

Answer (score 0):

The equation in $x$ : $ax\equiv 1 \bmod n$ has a solution if and only if $(a,n)=1$. If $n$ is not prime take $a$ a proper divisor of $n$. Then $a$ is not divisible by $n$ , while $ax\equiv 1$ has no solution.

Although note that $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is the group in which the elements are the congruence classes relatively prime to $p$. Not those that are not multiples of $p$.

Comment: yeah, I forgot to add the asterisk. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: you meant "take a proper divisor of $n$"?

Comment: oh yeah. thanks.